# How to correctly infer types in Mongoose callback functions?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm converting a Node.js application to Typescript v4.9.4, but I'm running into issues with Mongoose v6.9.0, specifically when trying to use instance methods. When I call certain query functions such as `findOne()`, the types are not inferred for the callback parameters `(error, document)`. Even if I explicitly give the second parameter the corresponding model type, it doesn't recognize the instance method as belonging to that type.

Strangely, I don't get this error when calling the `create()` function with a callback; types are inferred as expected.

Here is the relevant code, based on [Schemas: Instance Methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) from the docs, which claims "*there is no need to create a separate TS type to define the type of the instance functions.*" I tried making the user in the callback a `typeof UserModel`, but this didn't work either. I also tried setting up the schema following [Statics and Methods in TypeScript](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics-and-methods.html#methods), but I got the same error message. I know of a workaround ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798586/21087625)), but this doesn't infer the type of my method.

**user.model.ts**

```ts
import { HydratedDocument, InferSchemaType, Schema, model } from "mongoose";

export type User = HydratedDocument<InferSchemaType<typeof userSchema>>;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String,
}, {
  methods: {
    setPassword(password: string) {
      // setting salt and hash
    },
  },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

export const UserModel = model("User", userSchema);
```

**auth.service.ts**

```ts
import { CallbackError } from "mongoose";

import { User, UserModel } from "../models/user.model";

...

export function login(username, password) {
  // Types are not inferred in callback, have to explicitly name them
  UserModel.findOne({ email: username }, function (err: CallbackError, user: User) {
    // Property 'validPassword' does not exist on type ...
    if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
      // handle incorrect password
    }
  });
}
```

The full error message is

> Property 'validPassword' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, any, { email: string; name: string; hash?: string | undefined; salt?: string | undefined; }> & { email: string; name: string; hash?: string | undefined; salt?: string | undefined; } & { ...; }'.

**EDIT**: I haven't been able to solve this issue, so as a workaround I spun out the User instance method(s) into a separate service module. Personally I wouldn't recommend trying to use TS and Mongoose together.